# xamarin push notification ios Page navigation not working when push notification click

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I have azure push notification in Xamarin forms. when push notification received I need to open a page in my application. Its working fine in android. In iOS its not working when app is open. When app is in the background its working find in iOS.

This is my App Delegate code

```
public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo,
   Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {

        try
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
            NSError error;
            NSData notification = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(userInfo["action"], NSJsonWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, out error);
            string notificationString = NSString.FromData(notification, NSStringEncoding.UTF8).ToString();

            var NotificationObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationData>(notificationString);
            NotificationService.pushPageName = NotificationObj.Notification[0].PageName.ToString();
            NotificationService.pushAppName = NotificationObj.AppName.ToString();
            NotificationService.OpenPages = NotificationObj.Notification[0].OpenPage;
            NotificationService.Notification = notificationString;

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState.Equals(UIApplicationState.Active))
            {
                //App is in foreground. Act on it.
                var application1 = new App(NotificationService.pushPageName, NotificationService.pushAppName, NotificationService.Notification);
                LoadApplication(application1);
            }
            else
            {
              //  var application1 = new App(NotificationService.pushPageName, NotificationService.pushAppName, NotificationService.Notification);
            //    LoadApplication(application1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogInfo.ReportErrorInfo(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "AppDelegate-DidReceiveRemoteNotification");

        }
    }
```

after click push notification I need to open splash screen again.

This is App.cs Code

```
     public App(string openPageName, string openAppName,string notification)
    {  
            ServiceContainer.Resolve<IPushNotificationActionService>()
            .ActionTriggered += NotificationActionTriggered;
            InitMainPage(openPageName, openAppName, notification);
    } 

   private void InitMainPage(string pageName,string appName,string notification)
    {
        ServiceContainer.Resolve<IPushNotificationActionService>()
      .ActionTriggered += NotificationActionTriggered;
        PushNotificationActionService.PushNotificationPageName = pageName ;
        PushNotificationActionService.PushNotificationAppName = appName;
        PushNotificationActionService.PushNotificationMessage = notification;
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Splash(pageName));
     }
```

All methods are calling and push notification data also loading correctly in iOS. But not navigating to Spalsh Screen. Anyone have an idea to resolve this please help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#handling-foreground-app-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is running, we don't need to reload app with `LoadApplication` , we can directly send message to set `MainPage` in App.cs .

#### iOS

```
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationState.Equals(UIApplicationState.Active))
{
     MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this,"Hi");
}
```

#### Forms

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new MainPage();

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Hi", (obj) => {
       MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Splash(pageName));
    });
}
```